# Lot of pages under one node sitecore

Tags: sitecore

We have a requirement of storing 1000 location pages under one location folder in sitecore. I was looking best practice/suggestion of implementing.

Thinking of item buckets. but not sure how far it is feasible for content authors to design the page. Note, these location pages are not consistent in design. they often based on the location.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in Sitecore no more than 100 items per folder.

What often works well is a folder structure
Example: continent/country/{location}
or something alphabetical or by year/month.

A bucket can easy hold 1000+ item in Sitecore.
But a folder structure is automatically created that also ends up in the url.
so if it about the url should be location/{name} for all the items.
you need add a custom httpRequestBegin pipeline processor see:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/are-items-converted-to-bucket-items-still-accessible-via-the-original-path/9814

One more thing to mention a wildcard url can also work, if all have the same layout. See
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-dynamic-url-with-a-wildcard-item.html

Comment: Thanks for the response

if i store in buckets, how flexible for a author to find and author the page

Comment: There is a search included in the bucket for editors: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/using-item-buckets.html

Comment: a Faceted search, with the Sitecore editor.